# Tensorflow JS load TFHub model locally

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflow-hub, tfjs-node

I'm loading a model from TFHub via the `loadGraphModel` of `@tensorflow/tfjs-converter` package.

```
loadModel = function () {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
      return __generator(this, function (_a) {
        return [2, tfconv.loadGraphModel('https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/tfjs-model/toxicity/1/default/1', { fromTFHub: true })];
      });
    });
  };
```

This works fine. I have then downloaded the model locally for offline prediction:

```
.
├── group1-shard1of7
├── group1-shard2of7
├── group1-shard3of7
├── group1-shard4of7
├── group1-shard5of7
├── group1-shard6of7
├── group1-shard7of7
├── model.json
└── vocab.json
```

and I would like to load now this model locally. For other models, I was using the method `tfjs.loadLayersModel(this.path)` that support file protocol `file://`, but if I try to load this model I get the following error

```
'className' and 'config' must set.
```

In fact in the `model.json` these keys are missing.
I have tried to load the graph from the hub in this way:

```
var loadGraphModel = function () {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    tfconv.loadGraphModel(
      'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/tfjs-model/toxicity/1/default/1',
      { fromTFHub: true })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        resolve(res);
      })
      .catch(err => reject(err));
  });
}

GraphModel {
  modelUrl: 'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/tfjs-model/toxicity/1/default/1/model.json?tfjs-format=file',
  loadOptions: { fromTFHub: true },
  version: 'undefined.undefined',
  handler: HTTPRequest {
    DEFAULT_METHOD: 'POST',
    weightPathPrefix: undefined,
    onProgress: undefined,
    fetch: [Function],
    path: 'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/tfjs-model/toxicity/1/default/1/model.json?tfjs-format=file',
    requestInit: {}
  },
  artifacts: {
    modelTopology: { node: [Array], library: {}, versions: {} },
    weightSpecs: [
    ...
```

So how to load this TFHub `GraphModel` locally like saving and reloading from local file system?

Comment: As a workaround, you could use a local http server or write a custom IOHandler, see https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/save_load

Comment: @javadb9 so you mean hosting locally the GraphModel as served by TfHub and therefore just switching the url to something like http://localhost/api/models/model.json. That’s a cool idea. I have to check where to place the actual models files since requests should come from the same path.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by same path, previously they use to load the model through this url: https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/savedmodel/toxicity/model.json and it worked fine for them, see https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/e80d693bb43cb0ef234b808021c4def434ea816a/toxicity/src/index.ts#L55 
btw I am fawazahmed0

Comment: Hello fawazahmed0! thanks, so that model is a saved `GraphModel` basically. The other thing is that they changed the api. In the past there was `tf.node.loadSavedModel`, but now it was removed...

Comment: It seems to be there, https://js.tensorflow.org/api_node/2.4.0/#node.loadSavedModel  , if for some reason it doesn't work, you might want to raise an issue then, and remember it's only for node though

Comment: @javadb9 in fact, so it seems that it is there, but I'm getting a package issue for `tfjs-node` that is why it is not working! https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/4000

Comment: Yeah, I faced those problems before, thankfully I note things down on how I solved a problem by God's mercy, So just uninstall tensflow and tfjs-node, and follow the steps in my notes, remember making python 2 as default is important during the process,also the notes is about installing USE model, you just install your toxicity model instead :
Refer my notes : https://github.com/fawazahmed0/quran-verse-detection/blob/master/notes/node%20setup%20for%20tensorflow%20js.txt

Comment: In my case, I was using tf_saved_model generated files. I was able to quickly understand the issue is cause of CORS and tried s3/cloudfront - had trouble there hence decided to host it local on my filesystem on MAC using node `http-server -p 3004 --cors` and then reference the model url on loadGraphModel and it started working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for tf_saved_model -

Host the model files and shard bins on s3/localfilesystem setup with CORS.

I ended up doing this

```
npm install http-server -g

# where model files are stored
http-server -p 3004 --cors
```

On the React end using tensorflow-js

```
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs";
import { loadGraphModel } from "@tensorflow/tfjs-converter";

const net = await loadGraphModel("http://localhost:3004/tfjsexport/model.json");


const img = tf.browser.fromPixels(video);
const resized = tf.image.resizeBilinear(img, [640, 480]);
const casted = resized.cast("int32");
const expanded = casted.expandDims(0);
const obj = await net.executeAsync(expanded);
```